# sqlite undefined error in apportable when convert ios project to android

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, apportable, subproject

When i compile project tis issuse will be created. does sqlite support apportable 
?

Linking Build/android-armeabi-debug/touchandmove22/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so

```
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:28: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_open'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:29: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:32: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_step'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:34: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_column_count'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:37: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_column_text'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:40: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_column_name'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:50: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_finalize'

/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:52: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_close'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:70: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_open'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:71: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:72: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_step'
/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:76: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_finalize'

/Users/idc0013/touchandmove22/Database.m:78: error: undefined reference to 'sqlite3_close'
scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/touchandmove22/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Exception AttributeError: "`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'" in <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile instance at 0x10951aab8>> ignored`

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a regression in the Apportable SDK 1.1.04 release.  The workaround is to add a dep to configuration.json of "sqlite_3_7_5" (or go back to 1.1.03).

More details in this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/apportable/issues/detail?id=653).